# Get button properties from clicked button in control array

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need help how to get button proporties from a clicked button in a Control Array. I have dynamically created a number of buttons in an userform. When clicking on a button I need to get the caption from that button.

Something like this...

```
Dim buttonsArray() As New Class1
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim objButton As MSForms.CommandButton
    Dim buttonY As Long
    buttonY = 30
    For i = 1 To 10
        Set objButton = myForm.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btnNumber" & i)
        With objButton
            .Caption = "Button number " & i
            .Top = buttonY
            .Left = 10
        End With
        ReDim Preserve buttonsArray(1 To i)
        Set buttonsArray(i).CommandButtonEvents = objButton
        buttonY = buttonY + 30
    Next i
End Sub
```

And in my class module...

```
Private Sub CommandButtonEvents_Click()
    MsgBox ("I'm here")
    MsgBox ("Button caption is " & ClickedButton.Caption)
End Sub
```

The first msgbox works but the second is just there for show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ***Class1*** Code should be:

```
Public WithEvents CommandButtonEvents As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub CommandButtonEvents_Click()
    MsgBox "I'm here"
    MsgBox "Button caption is " & CommandButtonEvents.Caption 
End Sub
```

And in your ***UserForm_Initialize*** code, change:

```
Set objButton = myForm.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btnNumber" & i)
```

to:

```
Set objButton = Me.Controls.Add("Forms.CommandButton.1", "btnNumber" & i)
```

Comment: It's so obvious when you see the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Reference the **CommandButtonEvents** is the **MSForms.CommandButton** that you set in `UserForm_Initialize`.

```
Private Sub CommandButtonEvents_Click()
    MsgBox ("I'm here")
    MsgBox ("Button caption is " & CommandButtonEvents.Caption)
End Sub
```

Renaming **Class1** -> **CommandButtonEvents** and **CommandButtonEvents** -> **Button**, makes more sense to me.